# getting an xml from ajax - can't parse it

Tags: javascript, ajax, xml

I have

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "xml", 
    url: getUrl('/GetPeriodicStats/'), 
    data: XML.innerHTML,//some xml,
    success: function(c)
    {
```

c is an xml (a string represents an xml), I see I get it in the client side.
It is :

```
<command name=GetApLevelNumUlBytesSum all=1 >650</command>
```

and I'm tring to parse it, and get 650 in an alert, using :

```
    $(c).find('command').each(function(){
                var val = $(this).text();
                alert(val);
                });
```

or:

```
     var val = $(c).text();
     alert(val);
```

but I get no alert at all..
What did I do wrong ?

Comment: not getting alert or empty alert?

Comment: You said you get 650 in your first code but you get no alert at the code..what?

Comment: Subash Selvaraj, I get no alert at all .
 Bonakid, I'm expecting 650 in the alert, but no get any alert

Comment: can you check your console to see the error?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new with it.. in the console I see no errors ...
I get under respone tab : 
<command name=GetApLevelNumUlBytesSum all=1 >650</command>

Comment: Try this, xml = $.parseXML(c),
 alert(xml);

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Your code as below.

```
$(c).find('command').each(function( index, value ){
  var val = $(value).text();
  alert(val);
});
```

edited: to get the correct value.

Comment: can you do a console.log(value); in the above code and tell what its printing in the firebug console (with the edited xml as noted by edokan)?

Comment: I have another problem with the xml, a different one : I want to get XML.innerHTML in GetPeriodicStats which recieves it.. I know it's supposted to be in $_POST , but how can I get it ? I mean inxml = $_POST[??] ; –

Answer (score 0):

Try to use jQuery `parseXML()` function.

```
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
$xml = $( xmlDoc ),
$com = $xml.find( "command" );
alert($com.text());
```

Comment: didn't help, still no alerts

Answer (score 0):

your xml seems wrong. HTML does allow attribute values without quotes but xml does not.

Comment: I changed it to
    <command "name"=GetApLevelNumUlBytesSum "all"=1 >650</command>
but still no alert

Comment: try chaging it to `<command name="GetApLevelNumUlBytesSum " all="1">650</command>` and I think you have already set the content type to "text/xml" on server side.

Comment: Thanks! it works! I have another problem with the xml, a different one :
I want to get XML.innerHTML in GetPeriodicStats which recieves it..
I know it's supposted to be in $_POST , but how can I get it ?
I mean inxml = $_POST[??] ;

Comment: I now extended my xml to :
<command name="GetApLevelNumUlBytesSum" all="1" >750</command><command name="GetApLevelNumDlBytesSum" all="1" >400</command>
and again alerts don't appear